# C# DataObject with a Type object as data

Tags: c#, .net, types

I need to pass a Type as data using a DataObject instance. I tried the following code but the result is null.

```
DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(String));
Type result = (Type)data.GetData(typeof(Type));  //expected result to be typeof(String)
```

I am trying to do something like the following, but I am working with Type objects rather than String ones.

```
DataObject data = new DataObject("abc");
String result = (String)data.GetData(typeof(String));  //the result is "abc"
```

Any idea why I cannot pass Type objects using DataObject?

--- EDIT1 ---

I am actually using [`System.Windows.DataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobject?view=netframework-4.7.1) to figure out why `DragEventArgs.Data.GetData` method returns `null`. `DragEventArgs.Data` is an `IDataObject` and I use `DataObject` to simplify my test code.

Comment: I am not sure if this test is valid. Just because DragEventArgs.Data implements IDataObj, and DataObject also does so, you cannot imply they behave exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried [GetDataPresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yc0tt01(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: You maybe right, solving my problem with DataObject may not solve the one when using DragEventArgs. However, I noticed that both experience the same problem and thought that I could solve my DragEventArgs problem if I find a solution with DataObject. Should I ask another question using the explicit problem? Anyway, I don't understand why the code doesn't work in any of the cases.

Comment: Well, your edit kind of makes this question an x-y-Problem...

Comment: GetDataPresent returns a bool. Anyway, in the first example it returns false and I expect true in both examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to make it working. It also works with `DragEventArgs.Data`.

```
DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(String));
Type result = (Type)data.GetData(typeof(Type).GetType());
```

It seems that `typeof()` returns objects of type `Type` rather than `RuntimeType`. The only way to get the `RuntimeType` is to call `typeof(ANY_CLASS).GetType()`. I used the following code sample to figure this out.

```
string str1 = new Object().GetType().ToString();  //System.Object
string str2 = typeof(Object).ToString();  //System.Object
string str3 = typeof(Object).GetType().ToString();  //System.RuntimeType
string str4 = typeof(Type).ToString();  //System.Type
string str5 = typeof(Type).GetType().ToString();  //System.RuntimeType
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/):

```
 public class DataObject<T>
 {
      private T _data;
      public DataObject(T data)
      {
          _data = data;
      }

      public T GetData()
      {
          return _data;
      }
 }
```

Then you can do this:

```
 var data = new DataObject("abc");
 string result = data.GetData();
```

Comment: I did some testing with your code and it works as I expected it to, but that's not the problem. See my first edit.

Comment: That is a totally different thing. You should have mentioned that in the first place.